# How to define a firebase cloud function trigger inside a then-statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this code that I need to make sure is run before my firebase function is defined, because it depends on a variable set in the code:

```
const hotelBedTimeouts = [];

var beds = db.ref('/beds');

// Initialise the bed timeout holder object
beds.once("value", function(snapshot){
  var hotels = snapshot.val();

  for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
    // push empty list to be filled with lists holding individual bed timeouts
    if(hotels[i]){
      hotelBedTimeouts.push([]);
      for(var j = 0; j < hotels[i].length; j++) {
        // this list will hold all timeouts for this bed
        hotelBedTimeouts[i].push({});
      }
    } else {
      hotelBedTimeouts.push(undefined);
    }
  }
});
```

I was suggested to put this function inside of a `.then()` statement after the `once()` call. So I tried this:

```
const hotelBedTimeouts = [];

var beds = db.ref('/beds');

// Initialise the bed timeout holder object
beds.once("value", function(snapshot){
  var hotels = snapshot.val();

  for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
    // push empty list to be filled with lists holding individual bed timeouts
    if(hotels[i]){
      hotelBedTimeouts.push([]);
      for(var j = 0; j < hotels[i].length; j++) {
        // this list will hold all timeouts for this bed
        hotelBedTimeouts[i].push({});
      }
    } else {
      hotelBedTimeouts.push(undefined);
    }
  }
}).then( () => {
  // Frees a bed after a set amount of time
  exports.scheduleFreeBed = functions.database.ref('/beds/{hotelIndex}/{bedIndex}/email').onUpdate( (snapshot, context) => {
     // My code
});
```

Unfortunately, this cause my whole firebase function to be deleted:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'company-23uzc'...

i  functions: deleting function scheduleFreeBed...
✔  functions[scheduleFreeBed]: Successful delete operation.
```

Is it possible to define a firebase function in this way?

What is the way to ensure that a firebase function always has access to certain variables defined in the backend code?

EDIT:

This is my first attempt at a solution after Doug Stevenson's answer:

```
const hotelBedTimeouts = [];
var beds = db.ref('/beds');
const promise = beds.once("value");

// Frees a bed after a set amount of time
exports.scheduleFreeBed = functions.database.ref('/beds/{hotelIndex}/{bedIndex}/email').onUpdate( (snapshot, context) => {

  promise.then( (snapshot) => {
      var hotels = snapshot.val();

      for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
        // push empty list to be filled with lists holding individual bed timeouts
        if(hotels[i]){
          hotelBedTimeouts.push([]);
          for(var j = 0; j < hotels[i].length; j++) {
            // this list will hold all timeouts for this bed
            hotelBedTimeouts[i].push({});
          }
        } else {
          hotelBedTimeouts.push(undefined);
        }
      }
    });

  var originalEmail = snapshot.after.val();
  var hotelIndex = context.params.hotelIndex;
  var bedIndex = context.params.bedIndex;
  if (originalEmail === -1) {
    clearTimeout(hotelBedTimeouts[hotelIndex][bedIndex].timeoutFunc); // clear current timeoutfunc
    return 0; // Do nothing
  }

  // replace old timeout function
  hotelBedTimeouts[hotelIndex][bedIndex].timeoutFunc = setTimeout(function () { // ERROR HERE
    var bedRef = admin.database().ref(`/beds/${hotelIndex}/${bedIndex}`);
    bedRef.once("value", function(bedSnap){
      var bed = bedSnap.val();
      var booked = bed.booked;
      if (!booked) {
        var currentEmail = bed.email;
        // Check if current bed/email is the same as originalEmail
        if (currentEmail === originalEmail) {
          bedSnap.child("email").ref.set(-1, function() {
            console.log("Freed bed");
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }, 300000); // 5 min timeout


  return 0;
});
```

Still, it seems like the hotelBedTimeouts has not been properly defined at the time of function execution, look at this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '15' of undefined
```

I've marked in a comment in my code which line this error is for.

How can the list still not be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of function definition isn't supported by the Firebase CLI.  Instead, you should kick off the initial work *inside* the function, and cache the result later so you don't have to execute it again.  Or, you can try to kick off the work, and retain a promise that the function can use later, like this:

```
const promise = doSomeInitialWork()  // returns a promise that resolves with the data

exports.scheduleFreeBed = functions.database.ref(...).onUpdate(change => {
    promise.then(results => {
        // work with the results of doSomeInitialWork() here
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to do the work over again inside the function, only when the function is loaded. The work consists of initialising an empty array of arrays and objects which will be filled by the firebase function. So if I reinitialize it as empty I will lose important information. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My solution doesn't do that.  It performs the work once and reuses the results held by the promise.

Comment: Ah, because a promise can only be resolved once, thanks!

Comment: Yup, you got it.

Comment: Hmm, I tried your solution but I still have the problem with the work seemingly not being done at the time of function execution. I've posted more info in a update.

Comment: Also, it seems like the promise resolves every time I enter the firebase function. How is that possible?

Comment: As you said, the promise can be resolved only once.  It will remain resolved for all future function invocations on that server instance.  If Cloud Functions has to spin up another instance, it will have to run your initial code again.  Use lots of logging to figure out how your code is running.